# Information about Salesforce Mobile SDK

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android, salesforce-sdk-hybrid, hybrid-remote

Every time, i try to run the 'forcehybrid create' command for building a hybrid app, the command fails as it tries to connect to GitHub and we have a restriction to access GitHub. Is there any way, that we can have these templates copied to a local machine and reference it from there? If possible, what changes do we need to make? Do we need to update any files? Please advise.

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Can you let me know which git repo URL it is pointing?

Comment: Hi Mohit,

Below is the error message that i am getting when i run the cmd. I then came to know that my company does not allow github.

forcehybrid failed
Command failed: git clone --branch v8.2.0 --single-branch --depth 1 --recurse-submodules https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates "C:\Users\USER\tmp20200819T101207.177\SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates"
Cloning into 'C:\Users\USER\tmp20200819T101207.177\SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates'...fatal: unable to access https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Templates/': Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT